# Advanced custom fields Post Object image field not displaying in custom post type single.php

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I have a custom post type called associations. I have associated some custom fields to the post type using Advanced Custom Fields, 2 of which are Post Object fields. This allows me to show content from a post from another post type. I would like to display this information in the single-associations.php, I have followed the documentation on the ACF website but i am running into a problem in which the image from the post object available_products is not displaying this field is labelled "product_icon", the post object fields are as follows (coverage_highlights, available_products)please see my code below:

```
    <?php

$post_objects = get_field('coverage_highlights');

if( $post_objects ): ?>

  <div class="association-products-side-bar">

    <h3 class="text-center">Coverage Highlights</h3>


    <ul>
      <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <li>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>


          </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
    <?php endif;

/*
*  Loop through post objects (assuming this is a multi-select field) ( don't setup postdata )
*  Using this method, the $post object is never changed so all functions need a seccond parameter of the post ID in question.
*/

$post_objects = get_field('available_products');

if( $post_objects ): ?>
      <div class="association-products-side-bar">
        <h3 class="text-center">Available Products</h3>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post_object): ?>
            <li>



    <?php

                        $image = get_field('product_icon');

                        if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                                        <?php endif; ?>





                              <?php endforeach; ?>


              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?></a>







            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <?php endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass a post ID to `get_field`, it defaults to using the global `$post`. You need to pass the ID of each of the `available_products` posts:

```
$image = get_field( 'product_icon', $post_object->ID );
```